# Is it possible to add docker support to VSTO Add-in?

Tags: .net, docker, vsto, office-addins

I'm developing Visual Studio Tools for Office Add-in. It runs in VSTO Runtime 2010. Is it possible to dockerize the solution? I don't see option "Add docker support" in Visual Studio...

Comment: What exactly do you need to implement with a docker support?

Answer (score 0):

COM/VSTO addins always run in the context of their parent app (Excel in your case). If Excel runs and your addin is installed, it will be loaded. Now whether it is a good idea to install Office inside a docker container is a different question.